# Trying to get a basic google home action to call my web hook from the simulator

Tags: google-home

I did the following:

- Created a python flask API and ran it on a server using SSL
- Successfully tested the API using Postman
- Created a new project on https://console.actions.google.com/
- Created an action and gave it a name
- Skipped account linking for now (Later I also tried setting up linking without success)
- On the develop section I added my API as the fulfillment URL and saved
- On the test section I switched to "Speaker"
- Then I selected the suggested text

Results:

- No logging appears on the terminal where the flask application is running. So the action did not communicate with my web hook
- In the test section on the actions console I see "We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again."
- REQUEST, RESPONSE, and AUDIO are all empty
- DEBUG has the following information:

> 

```
{
   "response": "We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again.",
   "expectUserResponse": false,
   "conversationToken": "",
   "audioResponse": "",
   "ssmlMarkList": [],
   "clientError": 8,
   "is3pResponse": false,
   "clientOperationList": [],
   "projectName": "",
   "renderedHtml": "",
   "previewStartTimeMicros": "",
   "isEmptyResponse": false,
   "agentName": "",
   "servingModelOutdated": false
}
```

Looking for a little help to get me going. The console did ask me to enable "Web & App Activity", which I did. I also tried setting up endpoints for account linking but didn't see anything trying to communicate with them.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're encountering an issue with linking your Google Actions Console account to a project in the Google Home app. To resolve this issue, follow these steps:

1. Check Your Google Actions Console Account: Ensure that you are using the correct Google account in the Actions Console. Make sure it's the same account that you use for the Google Home app.
2. Link to an Action/Project: You need to create or link an Action/Project in the Actions Console. If you haven't already done so, create a new project or select an existing one and link it to your Google Actions Console account.
3. Enable Testing: In the Actions Console, make sure you've enabled testing for your Action. This allows you to test your Action with the Google Home app.
4. Link a Device: Ensure that you have at least one device linked to your Action in the Google Home app. This device should be associated with the project you've set up

We highly suggest taking  [Google Smart Home Codelab](https://developers.home.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-washer?hl=en#1). This Codelab will guide you through the process of creating a Smart Home Action for controlling a simulated device using the Google Assistant. It covers key concepts such as device traits, fulfillment, and account linking.